# How can I display leading zeros in a text field in sencha?

Tags: extjs

Example: Test-0001

In my case, it is dropping the zeros, and showing only Test-1.

Code-

```
items: [{
          xtype: 'textfield',
          itemId: 'txt_Barcode',
          inputId: 'txt_Barcode',
          flex: 1,

          labelWidth: 150,
          fieldLabel: 'Barcode',
          listeners: {
                  blur: 'onBarcodeBlur',
                  change: 'onBarcodeChange'
                  },
          bind: '{theRecord.barcode}'
},
```

Comment: It works: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lci
Are you sure you're using 'textfield' component? or what version is it?

Comment: Yes, it is a textfield. Version- 6.2.2

Comment: What is written in 'onBarcodeChange' ?

Comment: And how do you set value to text field? By typing or setting it programmatically?

Comment: onBarcodeChange: function (combo, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        var me = this;
        var view = me.getView();
        view.down('#txt_Barcode').setValue(newValue.toUpperCase());
    },

By typing.

Comment: You don't need inputId, first parameter of the function is textfield itself and you can setvalue to it:
onBarcodeChange: function (textfield, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) { textfield.setValue(newValue.toUpperCase()); }

Anyway it must work. What about 'onBarcodeBlur' code?

Comment: Okay. Is this anyhow related (in onBarcodeBlur)?

 var barcd = view.down("#txt_Barcode");
        if ((barcd.getValue() || '') != '') {
            var newbarcd = barcd.getValue();
            newbarcd = newbarcd.replace(/\s/g, '');
            newbarcd = newbarcd.replace(/\b0+/g, '');
            barcd.setValue(newbarcd);

Comment: I removed the " newbarcd = newbarcd.replace(/\b0+/g, '');" Now it is working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is regex which replaces the zeros. Here's the example you can use if you still want to filter the string: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lci)

Comment: Thank you so much.